# Does $ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 $ still apply on a general manifold?

Tags: trigonometry, manifolds

So the proof of $ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 $ rests upon Pythagoras' theorem and the definitions $ \sin x := O/H $ and $ \cos x := A/H $, where $O$,$H$ and $A$ are the opposite, hypotenuse and adjacent side of a right angled triangle respectively. However if I was on a general manifold with a metric tensor $g$, then Pythagoras' theorem would read

$$ g_{ij}x^i x^j = c^2 $$

which would not give me the desired equation above. So my question: Does $ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 $ only hold in Euclidean space?

Comment: $\cos^2x+\sin^2x$ always equals one. But with a geodesic triangle on a curved surface, $\sin x$ need not equal your "$O/H$".

Comment: Consider the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) for how the pythagorean theorem may look different on a Riemannian manifold. On a sphere it's $\cos c=\cos a\cos b$. Of course sines and cosines are ratios, not finite lengths.

Comment: The question is also interesting, because in a curved manifold the ratio between circumference and diameter wouldn't be $\pi$ anymore. Just to say.